# Yii2 dropdown multiple selected values

Tags: yii2, yii2-model

I used Yii2 multiple selection dropdown , it is working fine at create but not showing me selected values on update!

Form:

```
       $form->field($model, 'categories[]')            
         ->dropDownList($model->CategoryDropdown,
         [
          'multiple'=>'multiple'
          'class'=>'chosen-select input-md required',              
         ]             
        )->label("Add Categories");
```

Model:

```
public function getCategoryDropdown()
{
        $listCategory   = Category::find()->select('ID,name')
            ->where(['is_subcategory' => 'Yes'])
            ->andWhere(['status' => 'active','approved' => 'active'])
            ->all();
        $list   = ArrayHelper::map( $listCategory,'ID','name');

        return $list;
}
```

Controller:

```
 public function actionCreate(){
 ...
     $model->categories = implode(",",$_POST['Company']['categories']);
    ...
    return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,           
        ]);
 }

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);    

    echo $model->categories; //  1,2,4,5  values already assigned
    ...
    return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,                    
            ]); 
  }
```

Database:

1,2,4,5

How I can show multi selected values in dropdown when I update my recored?

Comment: show the update action (controller)

Comment: no logic used in update action but I'm updating my question.

Comment: is there any option? to explode these values in dropdown?  
like: dropDownList($model, 'categories', ''explode(",",$model->categories),

Comment: You save the imploded selected categories in create. right?

Comment: yes I saved selected values in create

Comment: The problem is related with how to retrive the selected value and then assign it to the  "model".......

Comment: @scaisEdge values already assigned in case of update,

Comment: Yes but they are an imploded string non an array of value for "selected" management

Comment: I think I need to use listBox

Comment: DropDown or list box the problem don't change.

Comment: I got the solution, just removed '[]' from   $form->field($model, 'categories[]')       replaced with  $form->field($model, 'categories')   , it is working now.

Comment: will you please tell what is company in here??

Comment: @EjazKarim company is a "model", i have a company table in database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

all your code is ok just need `echo` your $form->...

```
echo $form->field($model, 'categories[]')            
     ->dropDownList($model->CategoryDropdown,
     [
      'multiple'=>'multiple',
      'class'=>'chosen-select input-md required',              
     ]             
    )->label("Add Categories");
```

or use `<?=  ?>` in view!

Comment: You should use $form->field($Item, 'categories')->listBox($dropdown_data);

Comment: I should need to use listBox.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution:

Form

```
 <?= 
  $form->field($model, 'categories')            
         ->dropDownList($model->CategoryDropdown,
         [
          'class'=>'chosen-select input-md required',
          'multiple'=>'multiple'              
         ]             
        )->label("Add Categories");
 ?>
```

Controller:

```
 public function actionCreate(){
 ...
     $model->categories = implode(",",$_POST['Company']['categories']);
    ...
    return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,           
        ]);
 }

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id); 
    $model->categories = explode(',', $model->categories);        
    ...
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
         $model->categories = implode(",",$_POST['Company']['categories']);    
         ...
         $model->save()
    }
    return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,                    
            ]); 
  }
```

Comment: *@Shahzad Bhai*, How To Show Selected Values In Dropdown (Which Is Multi Select). Do You Have Any Idea Or Any Link.? Means, Whatever Values I Selected From Multi Select Dropdown, I wanted Those Values While Updating Time.

Comment: @NanaPartykar I have used a single column in db like category and store values comma separated  4,3,6,5 and I have used bootstrap chosen-select in my form, and above code was working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend to use Select2 from krajee it has all the options that you might need, using multiple in dropDownList() will make you able to choose multiple values but by pressing and holding Ctrl and choosing which is not comfortable as choosing them using Select2.

They did an amazing job i highly recommend anyone with this problem to use it.

Please check the documentations.
https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2